# Something has stolen my Ctrl+Shift+F12 shortcut key after a recent update. How can I find out what has stolen it?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

I use this shortcut regularly inside IntelliJ IDEA. And now it is stolen by something else.

It is not displayed in the Keybaord settings, and I couldn't find it with gconf-editor.

Any ideas what app is that and/or how can I change it?

Comment: What does it do now when you press these keys?

Comment: @Sparhawk It shows me a white cross-hair.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Does this white cross hair just spontaneously appear? Where is it located?

Comment: What Ubuntu version is this?

Comment: @Sparhawk the mouse pointer turns into a cross-hair.

Comment: @Seth: It is 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem! :) Turned out that I had pressed the F-Lock key on the Microsoft keyboard. And it doesn't have any indicator lights so I didn't know. And restarting the computer had no effect on it either.